# replace the word if found at the last in a statement

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

Title: New Belgium Sacramento Clips Beer and Sacramento Film Tour Sacramento

Word: Sacramento

what i want is to remove Sacramento word from the last in the statement. first and second should be as it is.

Title and word is dynamic. it could be anything.

Comment: simply use rtrim :  https://eval.in/620885

Comment: Title and word could be anything later. i am just giving an example. I want a dynamic way to replace word from title if it is last in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the last occurrence of the word you can use negative lookahead. This will work if the word "Sacramento" is not at the end of the initial string but you still need to remove the last occurrence of it.

```
function removeLastOccurence($search, $subject)
{
    return preg_replace(
        "~ $search(?!.*$search)~",
        '',
        $subject
    );
}
```

But in case you only need to remove it from the very end of the string you can do it like this:

```
function removeLast($search, $subject)
{
    return preg_replace(
        "~ $search$~",
        '',
        $subject
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using  (?!...)

```
 <?php
        $mystring="New Belgium Sacramento Clips Beer and Sacramento Film Tour Sacramento";

         echo preg_replace('~Sacramento(?!.*Sacramento)~','',  $mystring),"\n";

        ?>
    //New Belgium Sacramento Clips Beer and Sacramento Film Tour
```